# Regex Help - Identifying Symbols

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

I'm trying to use regex to validate input from the user, I'm wanting to allow any letter in the alphabet, numbers, spaces and the following symbols:

! £ $ % & * ( ) _ + [ ] : ; @ ~ # < > ? , . -

I've never been that good with regex as it confuses the hell out of me. This is the best I've got but it's not working properly because if I put a ? in the field I receive the error.

```
<?php
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    if (!preg_match('/\/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s!£$%&*()_+[\]:;@~#<>?,.-]+$\//m', $title)) {
        $error = "Photo name contains unsafe characters.";
        $solution = "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Try again?</a>";
    }

    if ($error) { echo("$error");
?>
```

Why am I always getting these regex things wrong, just when I think I'm beginning to understand, I soon realise I'm really not! :P

If anyone could help me out and maybe explain why my example doesn't work so I can learn from my mistakes that would be very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extra `/` before the ^ and after the $, this one should work:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s!£$%&*()_+[\]:;@~#<>?,.-]+$/m', $title)
```

Also the `m` modifier would cause `$` to match the end of the line, and allow someone to add any character after the first line, so you should remove it.

Comment: Ah, that does work! Thank you! So with the m modifier I should remove it to leave
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s!£$%&*()_+[\]:;@~#<>?,.-]+$/', $title); ? And just to check I understand why... the m would be if they where writing in a textarea and then created a new paragraph, after the first line they could insert anything they wished since the $ has stopped the regex check now? Does this still comply for single text input fields where only one line can be written, can this be "hacked" so to speak to make paragraphs/more than one line? Sorry if I misunderstood, still learning :)

Comment: Yes for the first question. For the `m`, normally `$` matches the end of the string, so a `/^…$/` regex matches only if the entire string is matched by the regex. But with `m`, the `$` matches end of lines, so a `/^…$/m` regex matches if a single line in the entire string is matched by the regex.

Comment: So for the majority of things such as checking a users first name or in this case, a title to an uploaded photograph, then an m isn't needed as you're just checking the string? And this is already identified with the /^ $/